# Whats wrong with this relationship in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I get this error in my basic ember application, couldn't figure out whats wrong.

`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'author' relationship on a 'question' with id 101 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (DS.belongsTo({ async: true }))`

```
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    question: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    fullname:  DS.attr('string'),
    email:     DS.attr('string'),
    questions: DS.hasMany('question', { async: true })
});

App.Question.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id:        101,
        title:    'How do I become an expert?',
        author:    201,
        question: 'Can I become an expert in Ember?'
    },
    {
        id:        102,
        title:    'Are there lives in other planet?',
        author:    202,
        question: 'What are the chances of lives in other planets.'
    }
];

App.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id:         201,
        fullname:  'Ruby',
        email:     'ruby@rails',
        questions: [101]
    },
    {
        id:         202,
        fullname:  'Jruby',
        email:     'ruby@java',
        questions: [102]
    }
];
```

order of loading

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/user_model.js"></script>
<script src="js/models/question_model.js"></script>

<script src="js/fixtures/question_fixtures.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixtures/user_fixtures.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your author needs to be async as well since it's supplied an id, and not a record.

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    question: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.belongsTo('user', {async:true})
});
```

Additionally the store shouldn't be defined anymore, you just define adapters/serializers

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

Comment: Wow. Works like a treat